# mySQL: Insert into select when value x = ' ' then value y = 6

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case-when

```
INSERT INTO Agent (agentID, agentName, locationID) 
SELECT DISTINCT pantodata.agentID, pantodata.agentName FROM pantodata
CASE
WHEN pantodata.AgentTown = 'Stirling' THEN locationID = 6 
WHEN pantodata.AgentTown = 'Dunblane' THEN locationID = 3
END
FROM pantodata

Pantodata table:
agentID  AgentName  AgentTown
100      John        Stirling
101      Jack        Dunblane

Location table:
locationID  City
1           Bannockburn
2           Dollar 
3           Dunblane
4           Falkirk
5           Menstrie
6           Stirling

Agent table:
agentID     agentName    locationID
```

I'm trying to insert the agentID from pantodata & agentName from pantodata into the agent table.  I am then trying to check what town said agent is within(from pantodata table) then assigning the locationID(within agent table) to a certain number depending upon what town they are from which is specified within the pantodata table.

Comment: I guess you should move the CASE to the select list.

Comment: I also have a table called Location which has a locationID and city.  Each city has a unique locationID.  e.g. Stirling 6, Dunblane 3
So if there's a way to do this from that table that would be more efficient but I am unaware of how to do this.  The locationID within agent will be a foreign key for the primary key(locationID) within location.

Comment: Add some sample data for pantodata and Location tables, and show us what you want to be inserted into Agent table.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few syntax errors in the query. Try the corrected version below.

```
INSERT INTO Agent (agentID, agentName, locationID) 
SELECT DISTINCT pantodata.agentID, pantodata.agentName,
CASE
WHEN pantodata.AgentTown = 'Stirling' THEN 6 
WHEN pantodata.AgentTown = 'Dunblane' THEN 3
END
FROM pantodata
```

Using `Location` table. This assumes there is a one-to-one relationship between `locationid` and `city` in the location table.

```
INSERT INTO Agent (agentID, agentName, locationID) 
SELECT p.agentID, p.agentName, l.locationid
FROM pantodata p
JOIN Location l on p.AgentTown = l.city
```

Comment: This worked, thankyou very much.  I have a location table, is there a more efficient way to link these tables instead of doing a CASE WHEN.  e.g. Location table:
 locationID location
 6                Stirling
 3                Dunblane

Comment: If it's possible that an agent's town is unknown, do LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' 

I have edited my original question so you can see the table format.